# If all rows in any column are blank then delete entire column + skip first row

Tags: excel, vba

How can I properly delete any columns where all the rows are blank except the first row (header)? Here's what I tried:

```
Sub deleteColumn ()
Dim TotalRange As Range
Dim col As Range

Set TotalRange = TotalRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(TotalRange.Rows.Count - 1, _
TotalRange.Columns.Count)

Set col = Columns("A:D")

With TotalRange
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(col) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Empty"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Empty"
End If
End With

End Sub
```

I have a spreadsheet export of all data in a database and some fields are not used. These fields are columns in the sheet and I need to delete the ones that have no data in the rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub deleteColumn ()

    Dim TotalRange As Range, col As Range, x as long
    
    Set TotalRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange  '<< need to set the range first
    Set TotalRange = TotalRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(TotalRange.Rows.Count - 1, _
                                                    TotalRange.Columns.Count)
    'loop backwards over the columns in TotalRange
    For x = TotalRange.Columns.Count to 1 step -1
        set col = TotalRange.Columns(c)
        If application.counta(col) = 0 then col.entirecolumn.delete
    next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. How can I set a range of columns rather than running this on one column so that it will delete any columns with empty rows? I use columns("A:E"), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe I'm unclear on what you really want to do.  If you just wanted to run this on a specific range then `Set TotalRange = Range("A:E")` should do it.  Do you mean you want to remove empty *rows* ?

Comment: I am trying to delete ANY columns that contain blank rows other than the header row. So I will need to apply this condition statement on all columns. When setting the variable 'col' it is only set to one column, but I cannot set it to multiple columns successfully.

Comment: My code already loops over all columns and deletes any empty ones, so clearly I'm still misunderstanding something.

Comment: If we're still not following, it might be worth putting together a sheet with dummy data, and marking (using fill color for example) the ranges which you expect to get deleted.  Then either add a screenshot or share the file via box/dropbox/onedrive/etc

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. Editing on my cellphone, and can't test my code even if I write it down.

Use something like `Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row` to get the bottom-most row number in column A.

Check if (1). the found row number is the largest row number in your sheet, which you can get via `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count`. And (2). that cell is empty. Only when both 2 conditions are met, can we confirm we can delete column A.

Then you can add another loop to scan all the column areas you want to apply the find-and-delete method.